# R: Deleting rows based on a value in a column from a large data set in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am working in R on data set of 104500 observations. I want to delete rows based on a column name "state" that has values "TX" and "NY".

I am using the following code

```
customers <- customers[customers$State != "TX"]
```

I'm getting the following error

> Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 11 (the number of rows), not 104541

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you learn how to use `dplyr`, and other packages in the `tidyverse`.  I find them to be an indispensable tool in cleaning data.

Here's how I would use `dplyr` to filter out both Texas *and* New York in your data set:

```
library(dplyr)
customers = filter(customers, State != "TX" & State != "NY")
```

Alternatively,

```
customers = filter(customers, !(State %in% c("TX", "NY")))
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you missed a comma at the end.

```
customers <- customers[customers$State != "TX", ]
                                              ^
```

So you select rows based on your filter, and all columns.

HTH

please provide a reproducible example the next time.